# What's exactly the right way to cite IEEE conference paper?

Tags: citations, conference

According to the IEEE reference guide, we should use standard abbreviations for the conference name. However, among academic publications, I have seen at least three different ways of citing a conference paper. For example:

- Authors, “Title,” *in Proc. of the IEEE Intl. Conf. on Robot. and Autom*. IEEE, year, pp. xxx-xxx
- Authors, “Title,” *in Proceedings of the IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation*. IEEE, year, pp. xxx-xxx
- Authors, “Title,” *in 20xx IEEE International Conference on Robotics and Automation (ICRA)*. IEEE, year, pp. xxx-xxx

My questions are:

1. what is the right way to cite the conference paper, or doesn't it matter?
2. when to use *in proceedings* and when not to?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no consistency on how a conference article is cited.  I use LaTeX, and my references do not come out as you've listed them.  There is no publisher field (the publisher appears in the conference title), and you need to include the address of the conference; e.g., S. Claus, 'How to take care of reindeers?' in IEEE International Conference on Animal Husbandry, North Pole, Aug, 2021, pp1-6.

Comment: It will probably depend on the place the document will be published, archived, etc. Check with the authority figures in that place, editor or Dean of the department or whatever. Also, look at how previous authors have done in that journal/archive etc.

Answer (score 1):

In any type of citing issue, it is best to ask the editor/conference head. Another way to go about it is the guides. All journals/conferences have citing guides. You could follow them.

Comment: Google scholar has great bibtex as well.